# How search for a pattern from a file in another file using aw

Tags: unix, awk

file1 looking like this

```
1234
2356
2367
```

file2 looks like

```
abc,a,1234,0000
wsw,a,2356,0001
ert,a,2367,0002
```

Basically I would like to use my awk command below to take a pattern from file 1 and match to the line that contains the pattern in file2. How may I accomplish this?

`awk -F',' '{  if ( $3=pattern from file1 ) print "line it matches in file2 }'`

Comment: my files are 3 rows of csv data.

Comment: just field 3. the data in file1 will always have a match in file 2

Comment: and do you need a regexp or string or numeric comparison?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it with `awk`
A search using google, you will see may hits similar to this.

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR {a[$1];next} $3 in a' file1 file2
abc,a,1234,0000
wsw,a,2356,0001
ert,a,2367,0002
```

`FNR==NR {a[$1];next}` store `file1` in array `a`
`$3 in a` test if field `3` is found in `file2` 
Then do default action, print the row.